Why threading is much faster than asyncio when processing multiple files in my case
I'm experimenting with asyncio and threading to figure out which mechanism I should choose in processing a large number of files. The experiment is simple that I just want to read the files and add some characters in the end of each line and write the lines back to the files. Below is my codes:
async def process_files(filenames):
    for filename in filenames:
        await process_file(filename)

async def process_file(filename):
    i = 0
    #await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line += f"{i}\n"
            f.write(line)
            i += 1

def regular_process_file(filename):
    i = 0
    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line += f"{i}\n"
            f.write(line)
            i += 1

#asyncio call  
asyncio.run(process_files(filenames))

#multi-threading
threads = []
for file in filenames:
    t = threading.Thread(target=regular_process_file, args=(file,))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
for t in threads:
    t.join()

#multi-processing
processes = []
for file in filenames:
   proc = Process(target=regular_process_file, args=(file,))
    processes.append(proc)
    proc.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()

When I timed the above three mechanisms (asyncio, threading and multi-processing), I found asyncio has execution time close to multi-processing, while threading has execution time about 2/3 of those by the other two. I thought asyncio should achieve similar efficiency as threading since GIT only allows one thread executing at any point of time. Or does python multithreading will make use of all the processors (for example, one thread with each processor, but if this is the case, shouldn't multithreading have similar efficiency to multiprocessing)?.
Thanks!

There seem to be multiple issues: 1. Why are you calling asyncio.sleep()? 2. Your two process methods are doing different things. 3. Are you running all three methods at the same time in the same script?

@JanWilamowski, thanks for replying. 1. I was trying with different ways to improve the efficiency of the asyncio call. I removed it from the codes and the results are still almost the same. 2. I made the two process methods identical, but the results are still the same. 3. the methods are not run at the same time in the same script. I made sure each of them were handling the exactly same files. Thanks!

Your async code is not doing any async io, you're just running the code sequentially

You are doing synchronous file operations in your async routines. Since process_file never yields the thread, it will block any other async operations

@thatotherguy, and tdelaney, I tried to add the line "await asyncio.sleep(0.1)" right before opening the file in the process_file method, but it didn't help either. What would be the right way to fix that?

Use aiofiles.open to open files and asyncio.gather to allow interleaving the processing of each file. Be aware that async is only faster if the cost of deferring execution is lower than the cost of blocking, which is not the case for cached disk io, and especially not for single lines written to a file buffer.

Your async code isn't utilizing asyncio. Additionally, Python's default open method is a blocking call. If you want to open a file asynchronously, you can use aiofiles
First install library using pip install aiofiles
And Here's an asynchronous version of the process_file function:
import aiofiles
import asyncio

async def process_files(filenames):
    await asyncio.gather(*[process_file(filename) for filename in filenames])


async def process_file(filename):
    i = 0
    async with aiofiles.open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        lines = await f.readlines()
        async with aiofiles.open(filename, 'w') as fw:
            for line in lines:
                line += f"{i}\n"
                await fw.write(line)
                i += 1

